# Database design: I need an entity in my database to be related to itself but also to be stand-alone

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am sorry if the title of question is not clear. I will try to explain below:

So I am trying to design a database for a Campus Housing App. The Rooms can be either Single Rooms or Apartments. Apartments are basically 2 separate single rooms that have sequential numbers. Meaning rooms numbered 2135 and 2137 are two single rooms that form an apartment. Whereas room 2149 is just a single room.

My Room entity table has the following fields:

[image: Rooms Entity]

Am I supposed to add a boolean field `IsApartment`? But then how can I keep track of which room is connected to the other room that makes up the apartment?

Comment: Just consider them all apartments. You have one-room and two-room apartments.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 different tables - one for single room and another for apartment. Apartment would need 2 columns ( for the 2 single rooms ) and they would act as a composite primary key that would uniquely identify the apartment. You can also define the foreign key from apartment to single_room to ensure that the apartment rooms are definitely single rooms.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean having duplicate data. I would need to add the room both in the single room and in the apartment. Then when querying for apartments I would need to check if the single room is also in the apartment table. Overall wouldn't I be losing normal form?
Wouldn't some kind of inheritance (overlapping) relation be a better solution?

Comment: well, what I mean't was to have the room_id stored in the apartment table and your apartment table would have room_id_1, room_id_2 as the composite primary key. You would just insert data into the single room table. If you wish to club two rooms to make it into an apartment , then you would take the room_id's of each single room and populate into the apartment table. if there are characteristics specific to the apartment, that would be captured in the apartment table. This design follows normalization and would not have any duplicates

Comment: Yes it makes sense for me now. Thank you, you've been very helpful!

Comment: @Rocky I agree with this approach but would make `room_id_1` the PK and `room_id_2` a separate unique key. A composite PK would allow the same room number to appear in multiple rows. In addition, this sounds like a symmetric relation (e.g. `(2135, 2137)` is the same as `(2137, 2135)`) so a check constraint to ensure `room_id_1 + 2 = room_id_2` could be useful to ensure only valid apartments are recorded and each association is recorded only once.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add another table "linkedroom" with fields *roomID* (JOINed to your room ID) and *linkedroomID*?

This way you'll have information about the second room if the first one is an apartment, and null if it's not.

Comment: This would mean having the two columns as Foreign Keys to the same Primary key which is fine. But that would also prevent one of those columns from being NULL.

Comment: My idea was to put in that second table only the rooms that have a parent room (two records: a,b and b,a for each such pair), Then a simple LEFT JOIN in a query would give the result I'm talking about. Of course there are multiple ways to structure this, depending on how much work is to be done in a query and how much in code invoking it.